# How to get the input field data stored in a state in 3 different components to my 4th component using a Call Back Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created three components and a parent component. The three components each have check bill information fields. The parent component has a save button. I want to send the data to a state in the parent element from each component's input field data when the save button is clicked.

Comment: Why are you yelling "call back function"? Please share a [mcve] so we can actually be helpful.

Comment: sounds like a good use case for a state management system like `redux` :)

Comment: dear sir,i have a scenerio where i need the callback function to use becoz existing code written the same way

Comment: yes absolutely @JohnRuddell

Comment: can you  Please help me on this @JohnRuddell

Comment: I don't know what you want me to help you with. Your question doesn't have context. To provide a useful / helpful answer i'd need to see your component / code setup and or the hierarchy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to pass functions from the component that contains all of these components to update their state values on parent.  Then pass a function to do something with the values of the checkboxes, also on the parent. Here's an example, let me know if you need clarification:

```js
class CustomOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <label>
      field 1:
      <input
        name={this.props.inputName}
        type="text"
        value={this.props.inputValue}
        onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
      />
      </label>
    );
  }
}

class CustomTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <label>
      field 2:
      <input
        name={this.props.inputName}
        type="text"
        value={this.props.inputValue}
        onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
      />
      </label>
    );
  }
}

class CustomThree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <label>
      field 3:
      <input
        name={this.props.inputName}
        type="text"
        value={this.props.inputValue}
        onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
      />
      </label>
    );
  }
}



class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue1: "",
      inputValue2: "",
      inputValue3: ""
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const name = event.target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state.inputValue1);
    console.log(this.state.inputValue2);
    console.log(this.state.inputValue3);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <CustomOne
            inputName="inputValue1"
            inputValue={this.state.inputValue1}
            handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <br />
          <CustomTwo
            inputName="inputValue2"
            inputValue={this.state.inputValue2}
            handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <br />
          <CustomThree
            inputName="inputValue3"
            inputValue={this.state.inputValue3}
            handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**EDIT**

I have updated my answer to make each a text input field AND to put them in their own custom components.  It is exactly the same concept, you just have to pass the update functions to the input fields, as well as the values.  All stored in the parent.

To do this a different way, you would need to use something for state management such as React's Context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: actually we have 3 component those state info need to be sent to parent component which is having save button @Chris Sandvik

Comment: and that is not a checkBox . i mean to say Check Bill information input fields in 3 different components

Comment: Ok so are they text input fields?

Comment: can be done using call back but am not able to crack

Comment: yes those are input fields, you have done with one components only

Comment: you can create input fields in different component which is not having button ,button should be available only in seperate component with onclick we need to save

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if this is it helps at all

Comment: THANKS you cracked !!

Comment: No problem!  not sure why my answer is at -1 haha